# Minimally Logged Insert Into

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, logging, insert, bulkinsert

I have an `INSERT` statement that is eating a hell of a lot of log space, so much so that the hard drive is actually filling up before the statement completes.

The thing is, I *really* don't need this to be logged as it is only an intermediate data upload step.

For argument's sake, let's say I have:

- Table A: Initial upload table (populated using `bcp`, so no logging problems)
- Table B: Populated using `INSERT INTO B from A`

Is there a way that I can copy between A and B without anything being written to the log?

P.S. I'm using **SQL Server 2008** with **simple** recovery model.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From Louis Davidson, Microsoft MVP:

> There is no way to insert without
>   logging at all. SELECT INTO is the
>   best way to minimize logging in T-SQL,
>   using SSIS you can do the same sort of
>   light logging using Bulk Insert.
>
> From your requirements, I would
>   probably use SSIS, drop all
>   constraints, especially unique and
>   primary key ones, load the data in,
>   add the constraints back.  I load
>   about 100GB in just over an hour like
>   this, with fairly minimal overhead.  I
>   am using BULK LOGGED recovery model,
>   which just logs the existence of new
>   extents during the logging, and then
>   you can remove them later.
>
> The key is to start with barebones
>   tables, and it just screams.  Building
>   the index once leaves you will no
>   indexes to maintain, just the one
>   index build per index.

If you don't want to use SSIS, the point still applies to drop all of your constraints and use the `BULK LOGGED` recovery model.  This greatly reduces the logging done on `INSERT INTO` statements and thus should solve your issue.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191244.aspx

Comment: I have a PK and a fair number indices on these tables, as well as some default values. The PK and indices I can drop and create, but I need the defaults during the INSERT

Comment: @Karl - That is fine then.  It will slow down your INSERT but your main issue was log size, which will be solved with the `BULK LOGGED` recovery model.  The speed boost is mostly just a bonus.  You will need to look to be sure that an inserted record isn't causing triggers to fire, since that might also increase your log files even in a `BULK LOGGED` recovery model I believe.

Comment: Doesn't using Flag 610 allow us to insert..into with minimal logging?

Comment: @MohammadSanati - Not in this situation. The table has a PK so this statement applies: "if a table has a clustered index and is non-empty, data pages and index pages are both fully logged regardless of the recovery model". That is from the page on using Flag 610: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190422(v=sql.100).aspx. There may be the argument of it being blank to start but if the insert happens in batches or if there is data already there, the log blows up.

Answer (score 3):

Upload the data into tempdb instead of your database, and do all the intermediate transformations in tempdb. Then copy only the final data into the destination database. Use batches to minimize individual transaction size. If you still have problems, look into deploying trace flag 610, see [The Data Loading Performance Guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd425070%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) and [Prerequisites for Minimal Logging in Bulk Import](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190422%28v=sql.100%29.aspx):

> Trace Flag 610
>
> SQL Server 2008 introduces trace flag
>   610, which controls minimally logged
>   inserts into indexed tables.