# Is there a congruent command to truncate for re-filling a table?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, truncate, transaction-log

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Minimally Logged Insert Into](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6266450/minimally-logged-insert-into)

I have a staging table that I'm going to truncate because a truncate isn't logged. Is there a flag that I can apply to the insert statement (or an alternate statement) so that refilling it will also not be logged in MS SQL Server?

Comment: You can learn about [bulk insert with minimal log](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190422.aspx). All other [inserts are logged](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/databasedesign/thread/2a731abb-7c72-4627-9e4c-a9cc00b23f13)